# The chemical reaction between lemon juice and polystyrene foam cups

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have noticed that when I have lemon juice on my fingers and I touch a polystyrene foam cup (I will refrain from using the term 'styrofoam'), the cup begins to break down, i.e., melt. I can leave fingerprints on the cup in this manner. What is it about lemon juice and foam cups? What is happening, other than what I see; the cup melting.

I have never tried replicating this using other citric acids, such as an orange. So, I don't know yet if it's just lemon juice that will do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not any acid in the juice, but [limonene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limonene), the natural, fragrant, oil found in citrus fruit, and similar terpenes that are good organic solvents.

In fact, these [oils are sold for the purpose of cleaning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071JGCQ2W). Note, though [limonene itself is considered comparatively nontoxic](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18072821), after it has dissolved the polystyrene, it might be a slightly more dangerous, since [any unreacted styrene monomer in solution is somewhat more toxic](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7818769).

Comment: Is it possible that the fresh juice from the lemon is causing a chemical reaction within the cup when used with a beverage? Or when the juice is added to a beverage, is the dilution enough to prevent a reaction?  Cold tea/fresh lemon vs. hot tea/fresh lemon.

Comment: Are you saying that limonene will break down polystyrene? Or that traces of styrene from manufacturing would leech into solution?

Comment: I'm not sure about depolymerization, but unreacted monomer might be present, as well as various plasticizers, such as phthalates. Though high temperatures will depolymerize polystyrene, I have noted a strong styrene-like odor when the plastic is dissolved, or even shredded, at room temperature.

Comment: I did up voted too early as dissolving polystyrene, or anything, does not involve the breaking of *covalent* bonds. I doubt for the sudden release of monomer traces as they should be negligible or absent in a cup which is likely thought to contains drinks. Good point for limonene, tough.